# Get difference between 2 JavaScript Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Get difference between 2 JavaScript Arrays.

```js
    var tagsStr = 'Tag 1,Tag 2,Tag 3';
    var oldTaskSelectedTagsArray = tagsStr.split(',');
    console.log(oldTaskSelectedTagsArray); // ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3']

    var newTagsStr = 'Tag 1,Tag 2,Tag 3,Tag 4';
    var newTaskSelectedTagsArray = newTagsStr.split(',');
    console.log(newTaskSelectedTagsArray); // ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3', 'Tag 4']
```

Using `oldTaskSelectedTagsArray` and `newTaskSelectedTagsArray` how can I get the difference of these 2 arrays?  In this case would be `Tag 4`

Comment: Use a functional library like Ramda: http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/index.html

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40369164/6011421